# Angular Material Stepper: Server side validation action

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using Angular v8 with Material v8 theme. I am using Reactive Form with Linear Vertical Stepper.

The user registration wizard has two steps with two different forms respectively.

1. credential (email, password)
2. profile (name, gender, address etc.)

The reactive form parts checks for client side validations, such as required field, email/date format etc. When a user completes the profile section and clicks the register button the data is posted to the API.

**Problem:**

When there is a server side issues such as email is already registered, I want to ***open the credentials form/steps*** so that I can highlight the form control to let the user know.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest having the api return some sort of response that your angular code would understand, which could then highlight the relevant controls.

Comment: @Viqas their is no issue in highlighting the form control. What I want here is open the credential stepper here.

Comment: code you post your code please